# Getting System Health info via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get System Health status via PowerShell? Info like CPU Utilization, Used RAM, CPU temperature, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the PowerShell can create **.NET Framework Objects**, I would recommend the [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for this task.

This class can be hassle to work with, but provides most of the functionality you need.

For a List of categories you can obtain simply call the static `GetCategories()` method:

```
[System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories()
```

---

To get you started I wrote a little demonstration:

```
$pc_prc = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")
$pc_ram = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes")

while(1) {
    $time = get-date
    echo ======================
    echo $time
    echo ======================
    $pc_prc_value = $pc_prc.NextValue()
    $pc_ram_value = $pc_ram.NextValue()
    echo " + Processor Load:   $pc_prc_value %"
    echo " + Available Memory: $pc_ram_value MB"
    sleep 1
}
```

**Note** that the `PerformanceCounter` class **does not** support the retrieval CPU temperature data as that procedure is highly architecture dependent.

Check out [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open Hardware Monitor

> The Open Hardware Monitor is a free open source software that monitors
>   temperature sensors, fan speeds, voltages, load and clock speeds of a
>   computer.

You can access the command line version here:

[OpenHardwareMonitorReport](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/pull/1115#issuecomment-616230088)

Example part of the output:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\OpenHardwareMonitorReport> .\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.exe

Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.8.0.2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Process Type: 32-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- HP 00F52W (/mainboard)
|
+- Intel Core i7-3770 (/intelcpu/0)
|  +- Bus Speed      :  99.7734  99.7734  99.7784 (/intelcpu/0/clock/0)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/1)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/2)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :  3791.39  3791.39  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/3)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :  3691.62  3691.62  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/4)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :       42       42       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/0)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :       43       37       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/1)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :       42       35       42 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/2)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :       45       41       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/3)
|  +- CPU Package    :       45       43       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/4)
```

- [Open Hardware Monitor Official website](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/)